# Exercise with task to connect to the page and get informations from there

Tags: python, html, python-requests

I am working on this task right now:
"Use BeautifulSoup and requests Python packages to print out a list of all the article titles on the New York Times homepage."
For now I can only connect to the page:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get("https://www.nytimes.com/")
if r.status_code == 200:
    print("Page opened successfully.")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')
else:
    print("Page not found!")
    exit(1)
r_html = r.text
exit(0)
```

So... my question is how can I use "bs4" library and source code from the page to find the information I want from there(list of articles from the homepage)?

Answer (score 0):

The sorting criterion/criteria (common tags, or html properties for articles) is the main challenge. What i have done below is to scoop all article titles that appear within the  tag.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get("https://www.nytimes.com/")
if r.status_code == 200:
    print("Page opened successfully.")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')
    result = soup.find_all('h2')
    headlines = []
    for i in result:
        if result.index(i) < len(result)-2:
            headlines.append(i.text)
else:
     print("Page not found!")
    exit(1)
r_html = r.text
print(headlines)
exit(0)
```

You may take some time to study the page source, as this will give you more insight into what properties are unique to article headlines (with with you can better **scrape** the information you want)